# Solve $\left( \sum_i J_i J_i^T \right) x = \sum_i J_i \cdot \alpha_i$ efficiently

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Is it possible to solve for $x$

$$ \left( \sum_i^N J_i J_i^T \right) x = \sum_i^N J_i \alpha_i$$ where $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$ is a scalar and $J_i \in \mathbb{R}^6$ is a vector

in such a way that I do not have to do a summation over all $\mathbb{R}^{6 \times 6}$ matrices ($J_i J_i^T \in \mathbb{R}^{6 \times 6}$).

---

#### What is the reason?

- $N \approx 10^5$ is quite large.
- On a GPU this involves 2 [sum reductions](https://dournac.org/info/gpu_sum_reduction).
- The left-hand side involves a $\mathbb{R}^{6 \times 6}$ sum reduction - the right-hand side a $ \mathbb{R}^{6}$ sum reduction:
  $$ \left( \sum_i^N  \mathbb{R}^{6 \times 6}_i \right)  x = \sum_i^N  \mathbb{R}_i^{6}  \mathbb{R}_i$$
- Reducing $\mathbb{R}^{6 \times 6}$ matrices $N$ times drains the GPU bandwidth.

#### What is my goal?

- Doing a **sum reduction** with a lower dimensionality. For example
  $$ x = \sum_i^N \mathbb{R}^{6}$$

#### Important notes

- The GPU is **memory bound** but not **compute bound**.
- Consider $\left( \sum_i^N J_i J_i^T \right)$ as positive semi-definite.

Thanks

Comment: As in your previous post, it is not clear that $\left(\sum_iJ_iJ_i^T\right)^{-1}$ even exists. Depending on the number and values of the $J_i$ there could be infinitely many solutions, exactly one solution, or no solution at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find a vector $X$ that is perpendicular to all but one of the $J_i$'s, then you can left multiply by $X^T$ to get
$$
\sum_{i} X^T J_i J_i^T x = \sum_{i} X^T J_i g,
$$
which will simplify to 
$$
X^T J_k J_k^T x = X^T J_k g
$$
where we assume that $X^T J_k \neq 0$. This simplifies to
$$
J_k^T x = g
$$
which, as in your previous question, has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: I updated the question. Please revise. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_i J_i J_i^T$ is a positive semidefinite matrix, positive definite if the inverse exists.  The Cholesky decomposition is then then both efficient and numerically stable.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not really solving the system of equation. It's more the reduction step.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your rationale exactly, but what about conjugate gradient? This will solve your problem exactly in exactly $6$ steps (and $6$ gradient evaluations/ matrix $A=\sum J_iJ_i^T$ vector multiplies). You don't need to actually compute $A$ itself, you only need to compute $Ax$, for vectors, which can be done by computing the individual $J_i\times(J_i\cdot x)$ terms in the sum.

Comment: That sounds promising, can you elaborate a little please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method All you need to do is evaluate gradients and other much smaller calculations to do conjugate gradient. There is a theorem somewhere that says that conjugate gradient will converge to the exact solution in exactly $N$ steps, where $N$ is the number of dimensions. IN your case $N=6$, so this will be rather fast.

Comment: What kind of elaboration do you need?